# Invalid version of beats protocol: -128

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, filebeat

I have a problème receiving logs on a logstash instance from a backend server using beats input:

On the backend server, the filebeat logs says that it's failing to connect to the logstash instance:

```
Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://some-logstash-dns:8044)): dial tcp some-logstash-ip-address:8044: i/o timeout
```

On the logstash server, the logstash logs says that it's unable to decode the input due to invalid protocole version:

```
Handling exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.logstash.beats.InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid version of beats protocol: -128 (caused by: org.logstash.beats.InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid version of beats protocol: -128)
```

As a side note the stack is deployed on AWS using Cloud Formation. It's working as expected on the Development and Pre Production environments but ***NOT*** on the Production environment.

I also made sure that the output.logstash on the filebeat.yml is uncommented and the elasticsearch.output is commented

```
output.logstash:
hosts: ["some-logstash-dns:8044"]

...

#output.elasticsearch:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your logstash input? Share your config. _Invalid version of beats protocol_ normally means that you have something trying to send messages to the beats input without using the beats protocol, for example if you have something between filebeat and logstash like a proxy etc. What is the network differences between the Production environment and the other environments?